# MsSql Compare specific datetimes in sequence based on ID

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table where we store our data from a call and it looks like this:

```
CallID Arrive_Seq    DateTime                  ActivitytypeID
1         1          2018-01-01 05:00:00            1
1         2          2018-01-01 05:00:01            2
1         3          2018-01-01 06:00:00            21
1         4          2018-01-01 06:00:01            28
1         5          2018-01-01 06:00:02            13
1         6          2018-01-01 06:00:03            22
1         7          2018-01-01 06:00:05            29
1         8          2018-01-01 06:05:00            21
1         9          2018-01-01 06:05:01            28
1         10         2018-01-01 06:05:02            13
1         11         2018-01-01 06:05:03            22
1         12         2018-01-01 06:07:45            29
```

Now I want to select the datediff between ActivitytypeID 21 and 29 in the arrive_sew order. In this example they occur twice (on arrive_seq 3,8 and 7,12). This order is not specific and ActivitytypeID can occur both more and less times in the sequence but they are always connected with eachother. Think of it as `ActivitytypeID 21 = 'call started' AND ActivitytypeID = 29 'Call ended'`.

In the example the answer whould be:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF (SECOND, '2018-01-01 06:00:00', '2018-01-01 06:00:05') = 5  -- Compares datetime of arrive_seq 3 and 7
AND
SELECT DATEDIFF (SECOND, '2018-01-01 06:00:05', '2018-01-01 06:07:45') = 460 -- Compares datetime of arrive_seq 21 and 29
Total duration = 465
```

I have tried with this code but it doesn't work all the time due to row# can change based on arrive_seq and ActivitytypeID

```
;WITH CallbackDuration AS (
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY a.time_stamp ASC) AS RowNumber, DATEDIFF(second, a.time_stamp, b.time_stamp) AS 'Duration'
FROM Table a
JOIN Table b on a.call_id = b.call_id 
WHERE a.call_id = 1 AND a.activity_type = 21 AND b.activity_type = 29 
GROUP BY a.time_stamp, b.time_stamp,a.call_id)
SELECT SUM(Duration) AS 'Duration' FROM CallbackDuration WHERE RowNumber in (1,5,9)
```

Comment: What is your SQL version?

Comment: Hi, its Microsoft SQL Server Standard (64-bit) 2016

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
select
    call_start,
    call_end,
    datediff (second, call_start, call_end) as duration
from
    (
        select
            call_timestamp as call_end,
            lag(call_timestamp) over (partition by call_id order by call_timestamp) as call_start,
            activity_type as call_end_activity,
            lag (activity_type)  over (partition by call_id order by call_timestamp) as call_start_activity
        from 
            call_log
        where
            activity_type in (21, 29)
    ) x
where
    call_start_activity = 21;
```

Result:

```
call_start              call_end                duration
----------------------- ----------------------- -----------
2018-01-01 06:00:00.000 2018-01-01 06:00:05.000           5
2018-01-01 06:05:00.000 2018-01-01 06:07:45.000         165

(2 rows affected)
```

Note that the time of the second call is based on your sample data with start time 2018-01-01 06:05:00

Comment: Hi Ron, Yes this code does solve the problem! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

This query seems to return your expected result

```
declare @x int = 21
declare @y int = 29
;with cte(CallID, Arrive_Seq, DateTime, ActivitytypeID) as (
    select
        a, b, cast(c as datetime), d
    from (values
             (1,1,'2018-01-01 05:00:00',1)
            ,(1,2,'2018-01-01 05:00:01',2)
            ,(1,3,'2018-01-01 06:00:00',21)
            ,(1,4,'2018-01-01 06:00:01',28)
            ,(1,5,'2018-01-01 06:00:02',13)
            ,(1,6,'2018-01-01 06:00:03',22)
            ,(1,7,'2018-01-01 06:00:05',29)
            ,(1,8,'2018-01-01 06:05:00',21)
            ,(1,9,'2018-01-01 06:05:01',28)
            ,(1,10,'2018-01-01 06:05:02',13)
            ,(1,11,'2018-01-01 06:05:03',22)
            ,(1,12,'2018-01-01 06:07:45',29)
    ) t(a,b,c,d)
)

select
    sum(ss)
from (
    select 
        *, ss = datediff(ss, DateTime, lead(datetime) over (order by Arrive_Seq))
        , rn = row_number() over (order by Arrive_Seq)
    from 
        cte
    where
        ActivitytypeID in (@x, @y)
) t
where
    rn % 2 = 1
```

Comment: It very much did! Thank you very much for the example!